# Yii2 - jui datepicker extension - display current timestamp by default

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp, yii2

i'm using Yii2 extension - Jui DatePicker.

Is there a way to show by default the current timestamp in the text box, so the user does not need to input it every time it fills de form fields?

My view, and the form in Yii2:

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'data')->widget(DatePicker::className(),


                [
                    'language' => 'en',
                    'inline' => false,
                    'clientOptions' =>[
                    'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                    'showAnim'=>'fold',
                    'yearRange' => 'c-25:c+0',
                    'changeMonth'=> true,
                    'changeYear'=> true,
                    'autoSize'=>true,
                    'showOn'=> "button",
                    'buttonText' => 'clique aqui',
                     //'buttonImage'=> "images/calendar.gif",
                    ]])

                ?>
```

In Yii1 i used to write the code like this (inside the widget), and the timestamp appeared by default:

```
'htmlOptions'=>array('size'=>12, 'value'=>CTimestamp::formatDate('d/m/Y')),
```

Is there an equivalent in Yii2?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still use [`value`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-datepicker.html#$value-detail):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'data')->widget(DatePicker::className(),
    [
        'language' => 'en',
        ...
        'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
```

As noted in a comment (haven't confirmed this)

> `'value' => date('Y-m-d')` parameter will work only if widget is used without model: `DataPicker::widget(['value' => date('Y-m-d')])`

Therefore you can use [`clientOptions`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-widget.html#$clientOptions-detail) to set [`defaultDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) :

```
'clientOptions' => ['defaultDate' => date('Y-m-d')]
```

Or better yet you can set `$model->data` to a default value of the current timestamp, either in your view or in the model.

```
if (!$model->data) $model->data = date('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: `'value' => date('Y-m-d')` parameter will work only if widget is used without model: `DataPicker::widget(['value' => date('Y-m-d')])`

Comment: Many thanks, to you all. if (!$model->data) $model->data = date('Y-m-d');     Did the job very well.